# Extracting unique piece of text from file with awk, sed or grep

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk, grep

From the output of `pactl list sink-inputs`, I need to grab the *sink input* number for VLC. Before that, I'm trying to extract the piece that contains the output for only VLC. All the methods that I thought would work have shortcomings. This is a sample output:

```
$ pactl list sink-inputs
Sink Input #1373
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10350
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 453287 usec
    Sink Latency: 19697 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        media.role = "video"
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 2.1.5)"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "org.VideoLAN.VLC"
        application.version = "2.1.5"
        application.icon_name = "vlc"
        application.language = "pt_BR.UTF-8"
        application.process.id = "19965"
        application.process.machine_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4"
        application.process.session_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4-1431635199.85146-1790309877"
        application.process.user = "teresaejunior"
        application.process.host = "localhost"
        application.process.binary = "vlc"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:video"

Sink Input #1378
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10378
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0:  87% 1:  87%
            0: -3,63 dB 1: -3,63 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 989841 usec
    Sink Latency: 19572 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "mplayer2"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.process.id = "20093"
        application.process.user = "teresaejunior"
        application.process.host = "localhost"
        application.process.binary = "mplayer2"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.process.machine_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:mplayer2"
```

Both `awk '/^Sink/,/VLC/'` and `sed -n '/^Sink/,/VLC/p'` grab the VLC part, but then grab the mplayer2 part too and go until the end of the output:

```
$ pactl list sink-inputs | awk '/^Sink/,/VLC/'
Sink Input #1373
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10350
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 437414 usec
    Sink Latency: 19666 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        media.role = "video"
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 2.1.5)"
Sink Input #1379
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10381
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0:  87% 1:  87%
            0: -3,63 dB 1: -3,63 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 980045 usec
    Sink Latency: 19563 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "mplayer2"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.process.id = "20093"
        application.process.user = "teresaejunior"
        application.process.host = "localhost"
        application.process.binary = "mplayer2"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.process.machine_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:mplayer2"
```

`grep -Poz '^Sink(?s).*?VLC'` works, but if the VLC output should come after mplayer2, it would fail (a test with mplayer2 instead of VLC):

```
$ pactl list sink-inputs | grep -Poz '^Sink(?s).*?mplayer'
Sink Input #1373
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10350
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 441088 usec
    Sink Latency: 18159 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        media.role = "video"
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 2.1.5)"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "org.VideoLAN.VLC"
        application.version = "2.1.5"
        application.icon_name = "vlc"
        application.language = "pt_BR.UTF-8"
        application.process.id = "19965"
        application.process.machine_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4"
        application.process.session_id = "948146522454ae6aa2bb8ed153f4bce4-1431635199.85146-1790309877"
        application.process.user = "teresaejunior"
        application.process.host = "localhost"
        application.process.binary = "vlc"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:video"

Sink Input #1380
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10396
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0:  87% 1:  87%
            0: -3,63 dB 1: -3,63 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 989841 usec
    Sink Latency: 18084 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "mplayer
```

The desired output:

```
Sink Input #1373
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 9
    Client: 10350
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Buffer Latency: 441088 usec
    Sink Latency: 18159 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        media.role = "video"
        media.name = "audio stream"
        application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 2.1.5)"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `ed`:

```
ed -s <<'IN'
r !pactl list sink-inputs
/VLC/+,$d
?Sink Input?,.p
q
IN
```

It `r`eads the command output into the text buffer, `d`eletes everything after the first line matching `VLC` and then `p`rints from the previous line matching `Sink Input` up to current line.

With `sed`:

```
pactl list sink-inputs | sed -n 'H;/Sink Input/h;/VLC/{x;p;q}'
```

It appends each line to `H`old buffer, if a line matches `Sink Input` it overwrites the `h`old buffer and when a line matches VLC it e`x`changes the hold space w. pattern space, `p`rints and `q`uits.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use Perl's paragraph mode:

```
pactl list sink-inputs | perl -00ne 'print if s/(.*?VLC.*?\n).*/$1/ms'
```

The `-00` sets the input record separator to `\n\n` so a "line" is a paragraph. Then, the substitution will match everything until the first `VLC` and then anything until the 1st newline and save them as `$1`. Everything after that is removed (since we're replacing everything with `$1`). Finally, "lines" where that substitution was successful are printed.

Answer (score 3):

These are effectively multi-line records separated by a blank line. Awk is great for handling this kind of data:

```
pactl list sink-inputs | awk -v RS="" '/VLC/'
```

If you want to be really nit-picky about not including the bottom part of the record after the first occurrence of "VLC", then:

```
pactl list sink-inputs | awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '/VLC/{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { print $i; if($i ~ /VLC/) exit}}'
```